# Syntax for nested common-table-expression

Tags: t-sql, ssms, common-table-expression

I asked a question for a complex query yesterday, and I was offered an example. I really would like to get it to work but there was a syntax error in it that I can't figure out. Keep in mind that I was just introduced to CTE's earlier this week so hopefully this is an easy one.

I don't think I need to post the full code on here, so I'll just summarize

```
 with cte as (select dateadd(hour, 1, cast(cast(getdate() -1 as date) as datetime)) as midnnight),
 allhours as (
 select 0 as hour, midnight as timestart, dateadd(hour, 1, timestart) as timeend from cte union all
 select 1 as hour, dateadd(hour, 1, midnight), dateadd(hour, 2, midnight) from cte union all
 ....
 select 23 as hour, dateadd(hour, 23, midnight), dateadd(hour, 24, midnight) from cte union all
) 
select ah.hour,...
```

The (...) denotes unnecessary code that I omitted to make it less messy

But I am getting a syntax error on the parenthesis between select 23 and select ah.hour
"Incorrect syntax near ')'. Expecting SELECT, or '('.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few syntax errors including a `UNION ALL` that was not needed at the bottom, and your first `SELECT` in the `allhours` was referencing an alias, so try this:

```
;with cte as 
(
  select dateadd(hour, 1, cast(cast(getdate() -1 as date) as datetime)) as midnight
),
allhours as 
(
  select 0 as hour, midnight as timestart, dateadd(hour, 1, midnight) as timeend 
  from cte 
  union all
  select 1 as hour, dateadd(hour, 1, midnight), dateadd(hour, 2, midnight) 
  from cte 
  union all
  select 23 as hour, dateadd(hour, 23, midnight), dateadd(hour, 24, midnight) 
  from cte
) 
select *
from allhours
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/724f5/12)

Comment: Thanks bluefeet, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the last `Union all` here

```
 hour, dateadd(hour, 23, midnight), dateadd(hour, 24, midnight) from cte union all 
)  
select ah.hour,...
```

Also, spell midnight right in the first line

Comment: I think @bluefeet's answer is more complete - you should accept that one instead :)

Comment: I would up-vote your answer too, @podiluska but I don't have the required reputation yet. Sorry :/